AIX 7.2 cannot be pinged from other devices
first of all, I want to explain my architecture.
I have a machine that takes place in VSphere and i installed Ubuntu 24.04 inside of it. Then i installed qemu-system-ppc and qemu-utils package for QEMU. After that i succesfully setted up AIX 7.2 system.
My Ubuntu's network settings are configured manually. After that, I created a tap0 and gave it as parameter for running AIX 7.2 with QEMU. AIX 7.2 setting are configured successfully.
The problem is: I can ping 8.8.8.8 and my Ubuntu host from AIX 7.2 but I cannot ping my AIX 7.2 from other devices in same network. AIX 7.2 and Ubuntu have communication, AIX has internet but other devices except ubuntu cannot ping.
Network is VLAN by the way.
# ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap

# ip link set tap0 up

# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tap0/proxy_arp

# ip route add 192.168.10.x dev tap0

# ip neigh add proxy 192.168.10.x dev tap0

# ip neigh show proxy

# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE

# iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i tap0 -j ACCEPT

# iptables -I FORWARD 1 -o tap0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

My network codes are on top

The way you've written this question it is specific to AIX. Do you have the same problem when you run other virtual machines, or do they work as expected?
